# (KnockoutJS) How to detect if the html is re-rendered

Tags: html, performance, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm working in perfomance tweaking on Knockout.js  and I'm reading the post in the blog of [Ryan](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/03/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha-1ifwith.html).

I dont know how to notice if the browser is re-rendering HTML elements or sections in Chrome for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy way is to put a element like this inside the content that you are concerned about:

```
<span data-bind="text: (new Date())"></span>
```

Whenever, the entire area is re-rendered, this value will be updated.